# Having issues understanding class constructors in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I have the following code:

module ExchangeSocket =

```
type Socket(url, id, key) =

    let Communicator = new TestCommunicator(url)
    let Client = new WebsocketClient(Communicator)

    do
        Communicator.Name <- "test"
        Communicator.ReconnectTimeoutMs <- int (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.).TotalMilliseconds)
```

if we look at the last two lines, the C# usage is like that:

```
Communicator = new WebsocketCommunicator(wsUrl) { Name = "tst", ReconnectTimeoutMs = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds };
```

Now I read that to make a class constructor, I have to use the 'new' keyword; so I make the fields members and do a 'new' section:

```
    member this.communicator : TestCommunicator
    member this.client : WebsocketClient

    new() =
        this.communicator <- new TestCommunicator(url)
        this.client <- new WebsocketClient(this.communicator)
```

but this doesn't work (line 15 is the top line in this example)

> Socket.fs(15, 64): [FS0010] Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in member definition. Expected 'with', '=' or other token.

my questions are:

- How to make this work?
- What does 'new' bring that 'do' doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I read that to make a class constructor, I have to use the 'new' keyword

To make *additional* class constructors you should use the `new` keyword. The primary constructor is sufficient for you here.

In `member this.communicator : TestCommunicator`, while you have specified the type of the property `communicator`, you have not specified how to get (or set) this property. It is missing `= ...` or `with get/set` as the error message says.

```ml
new() =
    this.communicator <- new TestCommunicator(url)
    this.client <- new WebsocketClient(this.communicator)
```

When you fix the previous error, you will get another error here because 1. `new()` should return a `Socket`, and 2. it references `this` and `url`, which are not in scope.

Probably what you want is:

```ml
type Socket(url, id, key) =
    let communicator =
        new TestCommunicator(url,
            Name = "test",
            ReconnectTimeoutMs = int (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.).TotalMilliseconds))
    let client = new WebsocketClient(communicator)
    member _.Communicator = communicator
    member _.Client = client
```

While this answer does what you asked for, better would be to read the spec for classes ( See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/) and some examples of usage. Your code suggests you were guessing which is not the right approach.

Comment: I understand now; I went through the docs before, but it's kind of like having the six pack but not the plastic thing to tie the cans together :) now I see more clear. thanks! when you declare a member with _. is it the same as this.?

Comment: Thomas, in F# the 'self-identifier' (the name of the current instance) can be any valid name, not just 'this' like in C#. Also in F#, _ is used to signify that the actual name used doesn't matter. So taken together, you can infer from '__.' that in this particular instance member of the class, the self-identifier isn't used at all.